# Prove that $\left| \frac{z-w}{1-\bar{z}w}\right| < 1$ for $|z| < 1$ and $|w| < 1$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I'm asked to prove that, for two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ such that $\bar{z}w \neq 1$,
$$
\left| \frac{z-w}{1-\bar{z}w}\right| < 1
$$
if $|z| < 1$ and $|w| < 1$.

I began my approach by assuming that it's true so we can write

$$|z - w| < |1 - \bar{z}w|$$
$$|z - w|^2 < |1 - \bar{z}w|^2$$
$$(z - w)(\bar{z} - \bar{w}) < (1 - z\bar{w})(1 - \bar{z}w)$$
$$z\bar{z} - w\bar{w} - z\bar{w} - \bar{z}w < 1 + z\bar{z}w\bar{w} - z\bar{w} - \bar{z}w$$
$$|z|^2 + |w|^2 < 1 + |z|^2|w|^2$$
$$|z|^2 + |w|^2 - |zw|^2 < 1 \tag{1} \label{1}$$

If $|z|^2 + |w|^2 \leq 1$, \eqref{1} is trivially true. If $|z|^2 + |w|^2 > 1$, then $|zw|^2 > |w|^2(1-|w|^2)$, so
$$
|z|^2 + |w|^2 - |zw|^2 < |z|^2 + |w|^4.
$$
Now I'm left to show that $|z|^2 + |w|^4 < 1$, but I hit a wall. Not sure how I can do that. Moreover, this approach feels like a dead end, I'm just pushing the problem forward.

Is there anyway I can salvage this proof, or should I look for a different strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $|z|^2 + |w|^2 - |zw|^2 < 1 \tag{1}$

Move everything to one side and write it as $(1-|z|^2)(1-|w|^2) \gt 0$ with both factors positive.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense. Couldn't see the forest for the trees, I guess

Comment: @VictorSouza You did it the right way, just one small step short.